# Append HTML after adding record in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I have an Angular (v7) project and there is a comment list on a component as shown below. I list comments in an *ngFor loop and add new ones to the list. However I reload the list after adding a new comment and I think there is a better way i.e. appending the newly added comment by combining it with HTML that I have used with JavaScript before. But unfortunately I have not managed to define it (maybe due to the loop). Is it possible in Angular?

***#comment-list.html:***

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments">
    <div class="p-col"> {{ comment.UserName }} </div>
    <div class="p-col-12" [innerHTML]="comment.Body"></div>
</div>
```

I call the method below after adding a new comment:

***#comment-list.ts:***

```
listComments() {
    this.loading = true;
    service.listComments(this)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.records = data.Data;
            this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

I think I should re-create an HTML list using newly added comment's data and append it to the list but how?

Comment: `this.comments.push(myNewComment)` or `this.records.push(myNewComment)`... wala

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Thanks a lot, it seems to be OK but I just need some modification out of the scope. Regards...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  to do that. Suppose you have defined the `newComment` object. To update the list in the view, just:

```
this.comments = [newComment, ...this.comments];
```

It will insert the `newComment` object at the first place of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but **push** method seems to be easier to apply. Voted up ;)

Comment: @Willys I wouldnt recommend using push method. Using spread operator is safe than push and basically you create new array of comment without modify the old one

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc this could easily be done with `unshift` as well, you don't need spread operator